# Uploading image to server with Android HttpClient.execute(postRequest)

Tags: android, image, image-uploading

Here is the code...

```
Bitmap bm = myImageToUpload;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(myServerURL);
ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, imageName);

MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", bab);
reqEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody("image"));
reqEntity.addPart("mimeType", new StringBody("images/jpeg"));
reqEntity.addPart("extraInfo", new StringBody(extraInfo));

postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```

This code uploads my image along with some other information to the server. Is there a better way to do this?

My concerns - It is slow, Sometimes takes 20 minuets to upload a large image to the server. The size of the image on the server is larger than the original.

at the very least, how can I upload the image so that the image on the server is the exact same size as the image on my android device?

Comment: Is that the full code? I don't see any `.close()` there. Make sure you close the objects.

Comment: Why don;t you try to use a 3rd party library that will ensure to make everything work, since you give it a valid file?

Comment: That is not the full code. However there are no .close() in the full code. Wont the garbage collector take care of it though? or should I close them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reqEntity.addPart("uploadedfile", new FileBody(new File(myImageToUpload)));
```

This might be faster, and reads more easily, unless you really *need* the byte array.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. I have implemented it and  uploads are faster, also the file remains the same size. Is there any benefit to doing it with the byte array? I am just curious why the original programmer did it the way he did. Is the byte array more secure?

Comment: Byte arrays have a couple of features the original programmer may have needed.  They're useful for more than just file objects, they're filesystem agnostic and they can support random access -- but all of those things come at a performance cost, and you don't need them.  If you were to run a local speed comparison between byte-array transmission and stream read/write, you'd see a similar difference for similar reasons.